# AngularJS: making a simple stopwatch, a little confused

Tags: angularjs

Here's the code so far: http://plnkr.co/edit/DK9SSrIJZieSxDb5EN41?p=preview

Goal: press the start button and the seconds counter begins.
cant seem to get it working, the CountdownCtrl function should only start when button clicked.. so do i have two seperate functions, or how do i go about doing this.

Comment: As an aside: plnkr streaming is confusing as hell.

Comment: oops,ill edit the link to a normal one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My fork of your plunk shows how to do this. [Check it out](http://plnkr.co/edit/DDciwoBzFhQRjchyK1Mn?p=preview). I simplified your original code to show how you can make this easier to understand and to maintain.

First thing, you needed to initialize your module correctly.

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []); // the second param is your module's dependencies. since you have none, it MUST be an empty array
```

Next, declare your controller, and take in two dependencies, the `$scope` and `$timeout`:

```
 myApp.controller('CountDownCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) { // angular will inject the controller's $scope and the $timeout service
       // todo
 }]);
```

Then, declare an item on the `$scope` to store the counter value. This value will be accessible in the view. Then define a function to perform the actual countdown. It simply increments `$scope.value` and then sets a new timeout to itself, in effect calling itself every second until it is canceled.

Finally, add functions to start and stop the countdown:

```
  $scope.value = 0;

  // because of JS closures, $scope from the outer context will be included in countdown()'s context. 
  function countdown() {
    $scope.value++;
    $scope.timeout = $timeout(countdown, 1000);
  }

  $scope.start = function() {
    countdown();
  };

  $scope.stop = function() {
    $timeout.cancel($scope.timeout);
  };
```

Lastly, make sure your view instructs it what controller to use and add in the appropriate controller functions.

```
  <body ng-controller="CountDownCtrl">

    {{value}}

    <button ng-click="start()">Start</button>
    <button ng-click="stop()">Stop</button>    
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were definitely on the right track.  There were just a few things that weren't wired up.

Here is an [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dm98vN?p=info).

These are the main things that were needed to get everything working:

- Defined 'myApp' as the name of the module and wired up.  This allows controller to be registered correctly to the module.
- Make `CountDownCtrl` function a scoped function.
- Set up of the dependencies `$timeout` was moved to be registered against the controller (not the function).

**HTML:**

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-controller="m">

    {{value}}

    <button ng-click="CountDownCtrl()">Start</button>

  </body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('m', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {

 $scope.value = 0; 

$scope.CountDownCtrl = function() {

    $scope.value = 0;

    var change = function() {
        $scope.value += 1;
        $timeout(change,1000);
    };
    $timeout(change, 1000);
}

}]);
```